# What’s a practical daily application of each times table?

Tags: mathematics-in-daily-life

I’m teaching my five year old to read an analogue clock and realised how easy it is because (against teacher advice) I already taught him the 5x tables by rote.

He knows other tables too but they’re meaningless numbers to him. I’d love to hear ideas of practical everyday use of as other times tables so he can practice and improve them on a daily basis. I don’t mean games and exercises, I mean something you use without even thinking it. The 10x tables are easily covered with using money.

Comment: Because things can come in **n** per pack.

Answer (score 5):

A few off the top of my head:

7: calculating how many days away an event is when you know how many weeks it is (or vice versa)

All of them: estimating costs while grocery shopping

Comment: For example, how many are three six-packs of beer.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche that's a very important use case for a kid

Comment: @Ruslan, six-packs of juice in cans? :)